# Обновления для приложения

Tags: android, google-play

Используя unity3d, нашел 2 пункта в Project Settings:

1)Version Bundle

2)Version Bundle Code

Какое из этих двух полей нужно изменить, чтобы после загрузки на Google Market, приложение автоматически обновилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо увеличивать Bundle Version Code.

Для удобства понимания приведу аналогию из AndroidManifest.xml

```
Version Bundle - это android:versionName="1.1"(имя версии)
Version Bundle Code - это android:versionCode="2" (то что сверяется при загрузке)
```